# Can my button contain different fonts on mobile?

Tags: button, text, fonts, element

I'm trying to get my button text ("Shop My Look") to contain different fonts. I'd like "Shop" and "Look" to be font= Overpass (what they currently are), and "my" to be font= Amiri-italic. I'd also like the label to shorten to "Shop" when displayed on mobile. I've used the @media tag to alter the button in other ways for mobile, but I cannot get the text to shorten. I'm assuming both my issues are related in the fact that I need to separate the three words so that they can be edited/css can be applied to them individually. Not sure how to do this.

You can see my site here: [www.rachelclayton.co](https://www.rachelclayton.co) and find the button in question under the post in post-meta.

I've tried adding HTML:

## 1

```
<span Style= font-family: “overpass”>Shop</span> <span Style= font-family: “amiri”>my</span>
<span Style= font-family: “overpass”>Look</span>
```

## 2

```
<em>style=“font-family:amiri">my</em>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="shop-social">
<div class="shop-my-look">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Shop My Look', 'alder' ); ?>  
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 490px) {
.post-meta .shop-social a {
background: #ffff;
border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
color: #2e2e2e;
display: block;
font-size: 11.5px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 40px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
line-height: 40px;
width: 2em;
padding: 0 4px;
text-align: center;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by inserting  tag and using css to style accordingly. See following updated HTML:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
    <span class="shop">Shop</span>
    <span class="my"> My </span>
    <span class="look">Look</span>
</a>
```